# smoothscroll.js error event Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-events, smooth-scrolling

I have an error in the smoothscroll.js file on line 306 google chrome shows :

[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive.

The file is :
https://gist.github.com/jtangelder/40bbc2af02e0eb79b4ee

I have no idea how this file works. Can someone indicate what change(s) do I have to make ? Otherwise, do you have another idea in order to perform a smooth scroll ?

Answer (score 1):

there is a built in solution for smooth scrolling if it works for you:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it doest work well. I eneded up by deleting this file and the smooth scroll was still working !